# Can't find error on my code for Exercise 4-11. Getop Ungetch

Tags: c

I can't find the error. 
Visual Studio doesn't show error code.
And when I run it, it just goes into infinite loop.
It looks fine to me and looks it is supposed to work.
Please help me to find what I did wrong.

```
#define BUFSIZE 100

int getch2(char buf[], int bufp)
{
    return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}

int getop(char s[]) 
{
    int c, i;

    static char buf[BUFSIZE];
    static int bufp = 0;

    while ((s[0] = c = getch2(buf, bufp)) == ' ' || c == '\t')
        ;
    s[1] = '\0';
    if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.')
        return c;
    i = 0;
    if (isdigit(c))
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch2(buf, bufp)))
            ;
    if (c == '.')
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch2(buf, bufp)))
            ;
    s[i] = '\0';
    if (c != EOF)
        buf[bufp++] = c;
    return NUMBER;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] with _the input_. Also, you should mention where it gets into an infinite loop as there are a couple of loops there. And what is the code intended to do? How are we supposed to know what "Exercise 4-11" is?

Comment: Did you declare NUMBER in your getop() function?

Comment: sorry for confusion. I am not used to stackoverflow yet. This is K&R C Programming book exercise 4-11. everything is identical to sample in the book. Yes I have NUMBER defined. infinite loop is between while ((s[0] = c = getch2(buf, bufp)) == ' ' || c == '\t')
        ;  and called getch2 function. For some reason, bufp is looping between value 1 and 0. And that causes c value keep coming back to space.

Comment: In my view, there is absolutely no reason that I can find why bufp is looping 0 and 1.  So, getch2 is called with bufp value 1. buf[1] value be ' '.And bufp becomes 0. Then when it goes back to while, bufp refreshes back to 1 again for no reason.

Comment: I found out the problem by myself! It was because the function getch2 called the variable by value. ^o^. getch2 was changing copied value of bufp that's why bufp value was looping. I am so happy I found it myself. Because I read the book! haha